# GCP Organization wide service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-vpc

I have an organization with multiple projects. I must have a service that all compute, serverless, gke assets can connect to from all projects through https. Preferably this would not traverse the internet and would stay inside our organization.

Is this only possible with a shared vpc?

Comment: Shared VPC is your best shot, it covers exactly your use case and every administrative problem you might find in a multi-vpc environment.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Is there any other work around? Shared VPC won’t be available to me to use.

Comment: The answer is no. Traffic will "generally" stay within Google' backbone if you have Premium Tier networking, but some things like authentication, authorization, logging, monitoring, etc. are not within your control.

Comment: @rubio What do you mean? You don't think you'll be granted the Shared VPC Admin role ?

Comment: @john Hanley thanks I will look into the premium networks.

Comment: @pievis correct. I will not be granted that.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 platform-native ways to connect VPCs:

- [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc)
- [VPC Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering)
- [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview)

**Shared VPC** is typically preferable for organizations that have central control over their networking.  If you *can't use* Shared VPC, then your best bet for shared services is to settle for **VPN tunnels**.

You can use VPN tunnels between VPCs in different projects.  Packets will hit the internet, but they will be secure.